# A guide to the work of Timothy Gowers on Banach Spaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I'm undergraduate student and I'm thinking of doing my graduation thesis on some of Prof. Gowers work on Banach Spaces. It is not required to produce an original result in my thesis, I'm only asked to read some papers, understand them and write a new one which explains those papers and summarize them. I'm in my junior year so I still have one year before I start officially my thesis so I have some time to prepare my background.

I want some advice on the background I need to read and understand his work, which topics should I learn (more preferably, from which resources) in order to have an appropriate background to understand the works.

I have taken real analysis course and currently I'm taking measure theory and Functional analysis (we are using Kreyzig for functional analysis) and I have some exposure to combinatorics and probability theory but I have the interest to learn the required material even if the gap is big.

If possible, it would be great which works would be more accessible.

Comment: Start with http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-gowers and http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Gowers.html then read through the articles of Bollobas and Godefroy  mentioned in http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/References/Gowers.html

Comment: BTW, I suspect that the "reason to close" that is listed above was just selected by various users from the limited options available. I would have voted to close as "too broad".

Comment: In addition to @WillieWong's suggestions: if you want to focus on a particular result, then you might find this blogpost https://outofthenormmaths.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/jenga-blocks-and-gowers-hyperplane-space/ and the references towards the end helpful